# Trocar valor de td após validação

Tags: jquery, html, table, inner

Tenho o seguinte código HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="x">10</td>
<td class="x">10</td>
<td class="x">12</td>
<td class="x">18</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Através do jquery consigo pegar e verificar qual o valor dentro da `<td>` usando a seguinte função:

```
$(".x").text(function(index, item){
console.log(item);
{
```

Como faço para verificar se `<td>` tem o valor `10`, e assim trocar o valor `10` para uma string, e então jogar para dentro do `<td>` que tem o valor `10` de volta com o valor alterado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$('#appendButton').click(function(){
    $( ".x" ).each(function( index ) {
  if($(this).text() === "10"){
  $(this).html("VDC");
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
if (parseInt(item.innerHTML) === 10) {
  var novoValor = 50; // Implemente aqui a lógica do novo valor
  item.innerHTML = novoValor;
}
```

Você consegue pegar o conteúdo dentro da div usando o **innerHTML**.

Comment: parseInt($(".x")[index].innerHTML) === 10 ... $(".x")[index].innerHTML = novoValor

Answer (score 0):

Nao esqueca de adicionar um ID para melhorar a identificacao do elemento.
Mas acredito que o que queira seja algo assim:

```
$(function(){ // just jquery init
  $('table').find('td').each(function (index, item) {
    var itemContent = $(this).html()
    console.log( itemContent );
    if ( itemContent == 10 || itemContent == '10' ){
        // do something here
       console.log( item, index );
    }
  });
})
```